# Cassandra stress tool authentication

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-stress

I can't seem to get cassandra-stress working with authentication. I'm using simple username/password authentication. When I run cassandra-stress, I get auth failures (naturally). Anybody know how to specify username / passwords for stress-tool. I'm trying out apache cassandra 2.1.0-rc4 btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an old one but cassandra-stress got authentication support in 2.1.3 with [CASSANDRA-7985](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7985).

Answer (score 0):

I turned off authentication (stopped Cassandra, in conf/cassandra.yaml changed authenticator value from PasswordAuthenticator to AllowAllAuthenticator, then started Cassandra), then cassandra-stress tool worked.

Maybe it just doesn't support authentication?   That would be a little disappointing (version 2.0.9)

Ben